# Using Microsoft Graph API to access mutliple SharePoint online sites

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

We have developed a LOB app that utilizes AAD and Microsoft Graph.

The use case is that a user will log in to the app using the AAD credentials provided by his/her own organization.

Once logged in, the user needs to access the libraries on SharePoint Online tenants that are different from user's organization. Using Microsoft Graph, we can share the authentication token as part of the request **but whenever we try to access a SharePoint instance other than the instance owned by the user's own organization, we get a 400 error**.

For example, if the user belongs to contoso.com, s/he and all the guest users access the SharePoint libraries placed on contoso.sharepoint.com. If the user tries to access the libraries of myworld.com, to which the user is an external user, the graph API code throws back a 400 error.

The user can manually log in to myworld.sharepoint.com and can access the library etc. but when trying to do the same using graph API, it throws 400.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Well, I haven't really worked with SharePoint, but I can say there is probably a fault in your thinking. An access token is always only valid for one Azure AD tenant, since the token contains it. To access a specific tenant, the user needs to log in to *that Azure AD tenant*.

Comment: The whole concept behind Graph API, as I understand it, was to have user access information across multiple domains with the same credentials/access token. Apparently it is not something that Graph api is able to do as far as SharePoint is concerned... at least not yet as described in the article here. https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/791

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible. The token is *issued* by the AAD tenant (or the common MSA tenant for personal accounts). You cannot simply take a token from one tenant to use it to access another tenant.

Please note this has nothing to do with internet domain names. If Contoso owns and has validated `contoso.com` and `myworld.com` within the `contoso.microsoftonline.com` tenant then all 3 of those domains all point at the same tenant and represents aliases for the resource.

Comment: Then what is the purpose of Graph API? What i read on GitHub is that this currently is an issue with Graph API and is being worked out. Azure AD is federated and if it only is to work for the domain the id is created on then there really is no claim of cloud identity management.

Comment: Graph is a single API that overlays what used to be a forest of product/service specific APIs. Rather than having EWS, SharePoint API, AAD Graph API, Office Graph, etc. you have a single API to call across all these services. That said, you're confusing `domain` with `tenant`. Domains are an older construct and Graph will happily cross domains. That is a different scenario than a single token providing access to complete separate tenants.

Comment: So a person logged in as abc@contoso.com with contoso being one tenant cannot access resources e.g., SharePoint documents of another tenant xyz.com ? In other words, if I am added as an external user to a SharePoint, it is not possible for me to programmatically access the files shared with me. Only thing I can do is go to SharePoint website, log myself in and access the files?

Comment: I just tried and I am able to sync different libraries, from different tenants but for the same user id abc@contoso.com, as described in my comment above, using OneDrive App. All I want is to replicate this same functionality in my own code. Apparently it is something that can be done, I just need help finding how :(

Comment: If you are an external user on a tenant then you need to explicitly authenticate with that tenant. You cannot reuse a token from your home tenant.

Comment: How long will that explicit authentication will be valid for? Can we programmatically  take advantage of token renewal process once the user is authenticated with the external tenant? Essentially what i am thinking is keeping multiple authentication tokens in memory and presenting the appropriate token to the respective tenant.